# How to get custom object fields displaying in code completion in VS Code

Tags: vs-code

I am trying out the VS Code and wondering if it could be possible to display custom object fields while typing an apex code. At the moment the fields are not displayed:

[image]

But when I take some standard object like Account they are already there:

[image]

What is wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will answer my own question because I have found the problem (I think).

The autocomplete for custom object depends on the metadata definition, like @sfdcfox said. 
After updating the sobjects it did not work again. The tricky part is: my org has a **namespace**, so I should explicitly specify the namespace **prefix** to the custom object name in the apex code.

It is *not* necessary to do this in order for the code to work, but it seems to be necessary for the *vs code* to make the autocompletion work :(

So with a namespace prefix it works, without it not:

[image]

Answer (score 19):

Autocomplete depends on the metadata cache. To fix this, go to View > Command Palette (Ctrl-Shift-P), and type in "sobject". You should see a command "SFDX: Refresh sobject definitions." After that command runs, you should get autocomplete for all custom objects and fields.

Comment: Thank you mate! :) It is true, but I should have done additional step - add my namespace prefix to the custom objects name 8-()

Comment: Thanks, this really helped me...

Comment: thank you .. was driving me nuts!

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes "Auto-completion" still don't work even after refresh object definitions.

It is because of the Java Home Path not configured with the VS Code.

Answer (score 1):

I'll add a note here for anyone else who has attempted the above steps but is still experiencing issues (as I was):

Please ensure that you have the correct Salesforce permissions to access the field(s) you are trying to interact with in VS Code.